# Interpretation of plots (PCA, Volcano)

Tags: pca, data-visualization, interpretation

I'd like to ask if somebody can help me to understand these plots, the meaning of dots dispersion on the plots. I can't understand how to read these plots.

Link to the article https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7768686/

[image]

Comment: PCA plot: It looks like a mere 14% of the variance of the data was explains by the first two principal components, so the PCA plot does not explain most of whatever is going on. But I an see that the control and stroke groups are linearly separable.